# Separate page graphQL queries in separate files (.graphql)

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Is it possible to separate a page graphql query in a separate .graphql file, and then import it in the page file? I assume I need to add some kind og .graphQL loader?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your `query`, `mutation` with `.graphql` or `.gql` file extension.

You need `graphql-tag/loader`, here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: 'graphql-tag/loader'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [graphql-import](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-import) to do that.

Example: 
Assume the following directory structure:

```
.
├── schema.graphql
├── posts.graphql
└── comments.graphql
```

`schema.graphql`

```
# import Query.*, Mutation.* from "posts.graphql"
# import Query.*, Mutation.* from "comments.graphql"
```

`posts.graphql`

```
# import Comment from 'comments.graphql'

type Post {
  comments: [Comment]
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  tags: [String]
}
```

`comments.graphql`

```
type Comment {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
}
```

You can see full document in [here](https://oss.prisma.io/content/graphql-import/overview)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that's not possible out of the box. The only way to split up queries is with Fragments:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/querying-with-graphql/#fragments

However if you want to get a discussion started I'd recommend opening an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

check 'apollo-universal-starter-kit' - should be adaptable to gatsby